# Angular 4: How to use a Service and Observables to keep components updated?

Tags: angular, observable, angular-services, angular2-observables

I'm trying to understand how to use Observables and Subscriptions through a Service to keep my application in sync with the REST service it utilizes.

For illustration, let's say I were making an application that tracks Posts, Comments, and Replies. Every post can have a number of Comments, each of which can have a number of Replies, each of which could be found at REST endpoint
posts/{pid}/comments/{cid}/replies/{rid}.

In the application, this structure is displayed in an always-visible tree on the left. From other components in the application, new Posts, Comments, or Replies can be added, and when they are added the tree on the left needs to update.

So I know I should keep all of my HTTP calls in a Service, so that any component that needs to get data from the REST can access them. In examples or tutorials I've seen, the service might have a getPosts() method that GETs from /posts and returns an Observable, and the data-listing component (tree in my case) would subscribe to that Observable and assign the response to it's Posts[] object. But that's where the tutorial ends and my question begins.

So now let's say that some other component calls addPost() on the Service, which POSTs a new Post to /posts. How do I make sure my tree component gets updated? My tree component is subscribed to the Observable that was returned by getPosts(), but how would that subscription ever "trigger" again with new posts?

Comment: We've recently been using a model where the service exposes methods to trigger a fetch and an observable of the resulting data, which might fit your needs. I wrote a blog post on it: http://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Apr/09/async-angular-data.html